Xcode 15.3 module does not use additional module map
I have my own framework, Which is working fine since long time and also compiling in xcode 15.2. As soon as i updated xcode to xcode 15.3, My code is not compiling. I am getting below error.
module '' does not use additional module map '.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' not used when the module was built
I have both objective c and swift files in my framework.
I am trying to build my existing framework in xcode 15.3 which is working fine in xcode 15.2

Module 'ABC' does not use additional module map
'/Users/avinash/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ABC-ckofsggoxbykcfgdlmgkteeffuvq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC.framework/Modules/module.modulemap'
not used when the module was built

Error screen shot

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Added screenshot and more details @Community
